# The pipe has been ended when call from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write a .aspx web page to test my web service.
The web service will call a external exe to do encryption.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pgp.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

The pgp.exe can start successfully. but exception occurs at following

```
try
{
    BinaryWriter inBinWriter = new BinaryWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream);
    inBinWriter.Write(PlainText);
    inBinWriter.Flush();
    inBinWriter.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    m_evt.WriteEntry("PGP Encrypt: Cannot Stream the Plain Text into PGP, " + m_pgpExecutable + " " + pgpEncryptCommand + ":" + e.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    m_evt.WriteEntry(PlainText.Length.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    throw new PGPException(PGPErrorCode.PGPProcessError, e.Message);
}
```

the eventlog shows:

```
PGP Encrypt: Cannot Stream the Plain Text into PGP, pgp.exe :System.IO.IOException: The pipe has been ended.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at PGPServer.PGPWrapper.doEncrypt(String UserName, String ChannelName, Byte[] PlainText, Byte[]& CipherText, String SenderName) in ...
```

that's all I get, I have no clue what happens, any help will be appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044133/wcf-named-pipe-io-exception-the-pipe-has-been-ended-109-0x6d)'s a possible solution.

Comment: I have tried to configure the Application Pool to recycling later, but the problem persist. I wonder if the "PlainText" is too large. However, it is just 4061 byte and other call to my web service ok!(not my testing aspx), which is the most strange part!

Comment: The problem is gone when I use a smaller file. So I guess it's related to filesize. But I still dun understand why 4061byte will cause the pipe to close.